# Start interactive zsh without running any configuration files like .zshrc

Tags: zsh

How can I start an interactive zsh without running any configuration files like `.zshrc`?

I tried `zsh -d -f -i`, but the prompt was the same as specified in `~/.zshrc`, so those options don't seem to have worked.

I'm running zsh 5.8 on macOS 10.15.4.

Comment: Do you make the mistake of exporting your prompt variables?

Comment: @JdeBP: Yes, I did.  How can I start a new interactive zsh that ignores either all existing exports, or specified existing exports?

Comment: Well, unexport them. `typeset +x PS1`. Or start it as `env - FOO=bar zsh`.

Answer (score 14):

`zsh -d -f -i` is correct for that, though `-d` (implied by `-f`) and `-i` (`zsh` runs interactively anyway when not given any script/code to run on the command line and stdin is a terminal) would be redundant.

Note however that `/etc/zsh/zshenv` is still interpreted and I don't think there's any way to disabled that. See `info zsh RCS` for details.

In your case, `PS1` was inherited from the environment. `PS1` is one of many environment variables that can also customize the shell.

Note that earliest shells had no rc file, customisation was done with environment variables only (which you'd set in the `~/.profile` or `~/.login`, interpreted by the login shell).

There are a large numbers of variables used to configure the shell. See:

```
info zsh 'Parameters Used By The Shell'
```

for details (note though that for some of them, the value found in the environment is ignored).

Some of those environment variables, like `HOME`, `PATH`, `SHELL`, `COLUMNS`, `LANG`, `LC_*` are used by many other programs than the shell, so it's not a good idea to unset them, or to use `env -i` to unset them all.

Most of those variables listed in that documentation you would not want to put in the environment, but declare them in your `~/.zshrc` instead as normal shell variables. `PS1` is one of them. `PS1` is used as the prompt customisation variable in many shells, but the syntax varies greatly between shell.

Unfortunately, some GNU/Linux distributions do set and export the `PS1` variable in some system start-up file, and define it with a value specific to the syntax of the `bash` shell (the GNU shell), which means that if you start any shell other than `bash` in an environment with that `PS1`, you get a garbage prompt.

To start a shell with `PS1` removed from the environment, you can do:

```
(unset -v PS1; zsh -f)
```

With some `env` implementations, you can also do:

```
env -u PS1 zsh -f
```

To start it with no environment variable (though as noted above, it's probably not a good idea):

```
env -i zsh -f
```